# C++ How to unpack array values as function arguments

Tags: c++, arrays, macros

I have an array of Strings that I would like to unpack as arguments for a function like:

`Blynk.setProperty(V0, "labels", "label 1", "label 2", "label 3");`

Where the array of strings would be:
`labels = {"label 1", "label 2", "label 3"}`

This array is actually built from an array of pointers to objects with a 'name' member, like:

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i<NUM_OBJECTS; i++) {
    labels[i] = objects[i]->name;
}
```

Where the objects array is defined at compile time, for example:

```
class Obj+ {
  public:
    Obj(String name) : name(name) {}
    String name;
}

Obj obj1("label1");
Obj obj2("label2");
Obj obj3("label3");

Obj* objects[3] = {&obj1, &obj2, &obj3};
```

**Also this is an Arduino project (does not have access to full C++ features)**

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe. _"Where the objects array is defined at compile time."_ Show us. A proper [mcve].

Comment: I presume `Blynk.setProperty(V0, "labels", labels[0], labels[1], labels[2]);` is somehow unsatisfactory?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the labels array can be of arbitrary size.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings provided example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do something like the following:

```
#include <utility>
    
template <std::size_t ... Is>
void setProperties(std::index_sequence<Is ...>, char const * labels []) {
    Blynk.setProperty(V0, "labels", labels[Is] ...);
}


char const * labels [NUM_OBJECTS] = { "l1", "l2", "l3" };
setProperties(std::make_index_sequence<NUM_OBJECTS>{}, labels);
```

Since, however, the number of arguments is known at compile time, it makes probably much more sense to store the labels in a `std::tuple` and simply use `std::apply`.

Comment: `std::array` implements the tuple interface, so you can use it with `std::apply` as well :)

Comment: Awesome that worked! I'm not sure std::tuple is available for Arduino?